# discord.py v2. Adding a user reaction via buttons

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

So, I have a semi-working button to add a reaction to an embeded message. However, there are a couple of issues. I am still learning the interactions/buttons, so please bear with me :(

- First, the bot adds the reaction, not the user pressing the button.
- Secondly, after the reaction is added, the button shows 'This interaction failed' although the reaction was added??

Here is the code for the button:

```
class BananaButton(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label=f"Give Banana", emoji='', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def banana(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        button.label = f"Give Banana"
        await interaction.message.add_reaction('')
```

I also wish to make the button disabled to that user after use, if possible (but still available to other users... Not too sure if this is possible yet.

Attached is an image of the embed and button semi-working.

[Button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiCUP.png)

I've tried lots of things, but this is as close as I can get... Read documentation and can't work out where I've gone wrong and how to do what I need :(

Comment: I don't think the bot can add a reaction on behalf of a user. As for disabling it for a specific user, you can do that by overriding the `interaction_check` in your view. The button will still be pressable, but the interaction won't pass through. And "This interaction failed" means that the bot failed to respond to an interaction. One way to respond to an interaction is with `interaction.response.send_message`.

Comment: Ah darn... I was hoping a button could add your reaction :(

Maybe a counter could count how many times the button was pressed but not sure how to do that as the button.label is checked as a string not an int? I'm confused :(

I also don't want to send a message back, so how could I confirm the interaction without a text response? :(